# commandbutton .click JQuery issue

Tags: jquery, jsf

I'm new at JQuery and I'm having some issue:

This is the function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#editButton").click(function() {
                alert('test');

            });
});
```

and this is the button:

```
<h:commandButton   id="editButton"/>
```

Then the JQuery doesnt work, but if I change the h:commandButton to `<button>` it does work.

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: what us commandButton??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It is part of the JSF Framework. Although this should work fine and just for OP's information, the string values are actually referenced as a variable contextually and stored elsewhere to stay aligned with the mvc pattern of JSF. `but if I change the h:commandButton to it does work` Elaborate on this fact. Change it to what? What is the rendered output of the `h:commandButton` in your HTML? Is it not a proper button.

Comment: *"but if I change the h:commandButton to it does work"* What change makes it work? I don't understand. Overall your questions no information to debug the problem. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) yourself.

Comment: Sorry fellows, fixed the syntax. I pasted some wrong information.

Comment: are there some error in the console??

Comment: no, theres no error in the console.

Answer (score -2):

```
<button id="editButton">Doh!</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="editButton" value="Doh!">
```

I have never seen

```
<h:commandButton />
```

and it gives me nothing to click. However

```
<h:commandButton id="editButton">Doh!</h>
```

does produce an element that jQuery can find

[image]

(the dropshadow is added, actual element is just **Doh!**) and the alert() works.

Comment: <h:commandButton> is JSF tag that generates a <button> tag